# Nothing happens after yum install php72 php72-php-cli

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, php, vagrant

I ran the following commands twice to ensure it's installed:

`yum install php72 php72-cli returns`

> Package php72-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version

now running `php -v` returns

> -bash: php: command not found

Note: This is on Vagrant running centos/7 box.

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends from what repository those packages originate. For example, if you install something from SCL those packages typically go into `/opt` and therefore binaries do not (automatically) appear on PATH. Simply run `yum whatprovides */php` or (more ugly but still my favorite) `find / -name php 2>/dev/null` and check where the `php` binary really is and if you have that directory on your PATH.

Comment: @Fiisch You are quite a legend. Post that and i'll accept.

Comment: Added as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from what repository those packages originate. For example, if you install something from SCL those packages typically go into `/opt` and therefore binaries do not (automatically) appear on `PATH`.

Simply run `yum whatprovides */php` or (more ugly but still my favorite) `find / -name php 2>/dev/null` and check where the `php` binary really is and if you have that directory on your `PATH`.